# How to remove internal interfaces from class help page generated with Sandcastle or SHFB?

Tags: c#, interface, internal, sandcastle, shfb

I have a class that implements many internal interfaces and I would like that documentation reader cannot see that class implements all those internal interfaces because this information is irrelevant for the readers.

For example, if I have the following class:

```
public class MyPublicClass : MyBasePublicClass, MyPublicInterface, MyInternalInterface1, MyInternalInterface2, MyInternalInterface3
{

}

public class MyBasePublicClass
{

}

public interface MyPublicInterface
{
    // Interface members...
}

internal interface MyInternalInterface1
{
    // Interface members...
}

internal interface MyInternalInterface2
{
    // Interface members...
}

internal interface MyInternalInterface3
{
    // Interface members...
}
```

I want that documentation reader sees MyPublicClass as this:

```
public class MyPublicClass : MyBasePublicClass, MyPublicInterface
{

}
```

Is this possible to achieve with Sandcastle or SHFB and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on Sandcastle Codeplex Discussion - [How to remove internal interfaces from class help page?](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/discussions/284226)

Since I didn't get an adequate answer, I ended up creating a custom Sandcastle Help File Builder Plug-In that hooks into SHFB after reflection info is generated.

It then opens reflection info file and removes the information about implementing internal interfaces from types that implement internal interfaces and saves modified reflection info file.

Answer (score 1):

I´m running version 1.9.3.0 of Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI which have a DocumentInternals setting in the Visibility section. This setting only removes links to internal interfaces and removes them from the documentation, but they are always displayed on the class.

So I think there is no easy fix to accomplish this. Editing Sandcastle files is maybe a solution.